# Visual Studio changing csproj file settings

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, iis-express

For some reason, each time I run my web project under IIS Express, Visual Studio updates the csproj file, and changes the following settings:

```
<IISExpressAnonymousAuthentication></IISExpressAnonymousAuthentication>
<IISExpressWindowsAuthentication></IISExpressWindowsAuthentication>
```

Can anyone tell me why these values change?  That is, what could I be doing in Visual Studio, or what settings could I have, that could change them?  I'm certainly not consciously changing these settings anywhere - although I am running the project locally (and under IIS Express).

Comment: Could you tell us a bit more about the project? Is it FW or Core? Maybe the full content of the csproj?

Comment: It's a Full Framework Web App.  However, I can't give the full content of the csproj file.  I have tried it on a fresh web application, and the problem doesn't seem to occur there; so it's obviously some setting within the project itself.